# Strange behavior when add two UITableView's in one UIViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I had an interesting problem when I added a second table on UIViewController. At the first table (which is right) appears contentOffset in interface builder and in the application. [image][image]

I also try implement this with help container view. Result not changed. Any idea why this can be?

> UPD1: If I do this in code, all works fine.
>
> UPD2: I am using Xcode 5.0.1
>
> UPD3: Steps to reproduce:
>    1. Add UINavigationController, remove UITableViewController.
>    2. Add UIViewController
>    3. Add to UIViewController two UITableView's
>    4. Set frames for first UITableView {0,65,160,504}, for second {160,65,160,504}
>    5. If you added UITableViewCell to left table, you will see strange offset. If you run app you can touch it.

Comment: Can you share steps you followed to do this? I tried this and saw no such issue! (do share XCode version as well just in case)

Comment: Thanks @Geebs for you response. I am using XCode 5.0.1 and added steps to reproduce as UPD3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode 5? It could just be a bug with storyboard. I just recommend adding the UITableView from the code. Apple should iron out any bugs with Xcode pretty soon but for now, just add it from the code.

Comment: Thanks @Marzukr for you response. I hope you are right and Apple fix all issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I found the root of problem. If in UINavigationController set topBar as Translucent Navigation Bar (by default) then for the first UITableView that will be added to the UIViewController it will automatically set contentInset in UIEdgeInsetsMake (64, 0, 0, 0), but only the first one. Everyone else will have a default contentInset. As the most optimal solution to the problem suggest to set in a storyboard to second table the same contentInset.